# Codeigniter xml file not uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

When trying to upload an XML file in Codeigniter. I am working with eFax, trying to set up **Inbound Fax Delivery:** Enabling XML Posting. I am getting the following error anytime I do a test post using their Sample.xml file they have provided:

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

Other documents will upload fine. In my upload config, `xml` is set in the options for `allowed_types`:

```php
$config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|xml';
```

Why does Codeigniter not allow the eFax XML document type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured out why this was happening. By default, the MIME type was not set in Codeigniter's `mimes.php` config file. I needed to add an array of multiple MIME types for the `xml` MIME. Specifically, I needed to add `application/xml`.

So in `/application/config/mimes.php` I changed this line:

```
'xml' => 'text/xml',
```

To this (converting the `xml` option to an array):

```
'xml' => array('text/xml', 'application/xml'),
```

That fixed the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

this is the one I use:

```
'xml'   =>  array('application/xml', 'text/xml', 'text/plain'),
```

NOTE: paste it in `/application/config/mimes.php`