# not uploading txt and xml files in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to upload xml and txt file types file in the server but I am getting an error

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

then I check my MIME types (/application/config/mimes.php) and it's already set to

```
'txt'  =>   'text/plain',
'text' =>   'text/plain',
'xml'  =>   array('application/xml', 'text/xml', 'text/plain'),
```

and still getting the same error

Other files like pdf, csv, html will upload fine,

but I'm not able to upload txt and xml files.

In my upload config, txt and xml is set in the options for allowed_types:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|csv|html|txt|xml';
```

[Codeigniter xml file not uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366558/codeigniter-xml-file-not-uploading)

what solution is provided in this question I try but didn't work for me.

so, I posted a new question.

Comment: is your text file empty ?

Comment: i faced same problem .But only for empty file. if i write some text then it works fine 

My config code 

`$config['upload_path']          = './knowledge_share/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'zip|txt|doc|pdf|xls|xml';
                $config['max_size']             = 50000;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
`

Comment: Thanks, brother it's file issue, not my code issue

Comment: Once again Thanks brother
I'm trying this since yesterday and not focused on the file.

Comment: one more thought: did you try to get the mime type of the file you want to update with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php and in case it doesn't exist in mimes.php, add it?